# Vuejs 2.0 server-side rendering

Tags: server-side-rendering, vue.js, vuejs2

I have faced this problem with my project when I try to setup server-side rendering with Vuejs 2.0:

```
h is not a function

TypeError: h is not a function
  at VueComponent._default (__vue_ssr_bundle__:3158:17)
```

My `client-entry.js` file:

```
import { app } from './index'
app.$mount('#app')
```

My `server-entry.js` file:

```
import { app } from './index'
export default context => {
  router.push(context.url).
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(app);
  })
}
```

My `webpack` config for server build:

```
var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  target: 'node',
  entry: './vue/server-entry.js',
  output: Object.assign({}, baseWebpackConfig.output, {
    path: 'dist/server',
    filename: 'server-bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  }),
  externals: Object.keys(require('../package.json').dependencies),
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"',
      'process.env.VUE_ENV': '"server"'
    })
  ]
})
```

And my `server.js` file:

```
var layout = fs.readFileSync('./dist/index.html', 'utf8')
const code = fs.readFileSync('./dist/server/server-bundle.js', 'utf8')
const bundleRenderer = require('vue-server-renderer').createBundleRenderer(code)
var express = require('express')
var server = express()
server.get('*', (request, response) => {
  bundleRenderer.renderToString((error, html) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
      return response
        .status(500)
        .send(JSON.stringify(error))
    }
    response.send(layout.replace('<div id="app"></div>', html))
  })
})
```

PS: My client build works fine.

Comment: where is your component code ?

Answer (score 0):

`h` is the name usually given to the `createElement` argument in a render function and it's necessary to name it that way when using jsx

Comment: render (h, content) {
      return (
        <div class="row row-search-item">
          <i class={`fa-${content.props.option.type_image} fa fa-2 col-xs-2 col-sm-1`} style="font-size: 1.5em; border-right:dotted 1px #ddd;padding-bottom:10px;"></i>
          <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-11">
            <p class="text-info" domProps-innerHTML={ content.props.option.name }></p>
            <p class="sub-info"  domProps-innerHTML={ content.props.option.address }></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    },
I'm using this and everything is fine for client build.